# Laravel: Print the current route, with a different parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Considering the following route group in Laravel 5:

```
Route::prefix('{locale}')->group(function () {
    // ... Other routes here
});
```

All routes that are nested within this route group have views that extend a certain layout.

Somewhere in this layout I loop all available locales in my application, and I put links to change to this locale. What would be the easiest way to print these links in my view, keeping the current route and possibly the other route parameters but changing only the `{locale}` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem and came up with this:

```
app('url')->toRoute(
    request()->route(),
    array_merge(request()->route()->originalParameters(), ['locale' => $otherLocale]),
    true
);
```

You could turn it into a helper like `route`:

```
function current_route($params = [], $absolute = true)
{
    return app('url')->toRoute(
        request()->route(),
        array_merge(request()->route()->originalParameters(), $params),
        $absolute
    );
}
```

and call it with `current_route(['locale' => 'sv'])`

Answer (score -2):

Maybe just Type-hint the request and pass the prefix into your view through your controller and use it in your links:

```
public function ControllerWithLocaleLinks(Request $request)
{
    $currentLocale = $request->route()->getPrefix();
    return view('locale', compact('currentLocale'));
}
```

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why should that locale be passed to the view?